# System.Threading.Timer: Why is it hating me?

Tags: c#, .net, winmm

I just started messing around with C#/.NET/mono and stuff, and I'm trying to make a simple song player. For this, I am using `winmm.dll` (did not find an easy cross-platform solution). The problem is this: I need to update a trackbar along with the song playing. I have two functions, `Player.GetLength` and `Player.GetCurrentPosition`, which return the time in miliseconds. If I call them "normally", everything is ok. But I need to call them in a timer, like this:

```
new System.Threading.Timer((state) =>
{
    length = Player.GetLength();
    pos = Player.GetCurrentPosition();
    trackBar1.Value = (pos / length) * 100;
}, null, 0, 100);
```

This is `GetLength`, and `GetCurrentPosition` is similar:

```
public static int GetLength()
{
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(128);
    mciSendString("status Song length", s, s.Capacity, IntPtr.Zero);
    return int.Parse(s.ToString());
}
```

**The problem:** when one of these two functions gets called, the program just stops, without any warning or exception thrown. *Note: I am using .NET*

So I was wondering if you can explain to me where I got it wrong :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing I'd note is that System.Threading.Timer fires it's callback in it's own thread.  Since you are interacting with the UI, you'd either want to use System.Windows.Forms.Timer (as a component on the form) or invoke back to the UI, as follows:

```
new System.Threading.Timer((state) =>
{
    length = Player.GetLength();
    pos = Player.GetCurrentPosition();
    trackBar1.Invoke(new Action(()=>trackBar1.Value = (pos / length) * 100));
}, null, 0, 100);
```

Likewise, I am not sure if the Player class supports/tolerates multiple threads, but if not, there is the possibility that the whole callback needs to be invoked to the UI.

Comment: It works, but I would also like to know _why_. Could you explain to me exactly what happens?

Comment: In .NET (as well as in many other UI libraries on many platforms), the UI controls are not designed to be accessed from multiple threads.  This allows them to work more quickly, because they don't need to worry about synchronizing data.  In your case, .NET is actually throwing an exception complaining about the fact that you are trying to access the UI from a background thread, but because it is on a background thread, you don't see the exception being thrown.

Comment: So I guess the only way to interact with them when using threads is `.Invoke`, right?

Comment: The System.Threading.Timer class runs the callback on a thread pool thread, as documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx

Comment: Thats correct- you must Invoke before interacting with the UI.

Comment: Also, there are some tricky edge conditions around what happens when the Form or Control that you are Invoking to has not yet been painted.  Some details on that here: http://www.ikriv.com/en/prog/info/dotnet/MysteriousHang.html